# Sending images over sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to send an image file through a TCP socket in C, but the image isn't being reassembled correctly on the server side. I was wondering if anyone can point out the mistake?

I know that the server is receiving the correct file size and it constructs a file of that size, but it isn't an image file.

Client

```
//Get Picture Size
printf("Getting Picture Size\n");
FILE *picture;
picture = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int size;
fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(picture);

//Send Picture Size
printf("Sending Picture Size\n");
write(sock, &size, sizeof(size));

//Send Picture as Byte Array
printf("Sending Picture as Byte Array\n");
char send_buffer[size];
while(!feof(picture)) {
    fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer), picture);
    write(sock, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));
    bzero(send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));
}
```

Server

```
//Read Picture Size
printf("Reading Picture Size\n");
int size;
read(new_sock, &size, sizeof(int));

//Read Picture Byte Array
printf("Reading Picture Byte Array\n");
char p_array[size];
read(new_sock, p_array, size);

//Convert it Back into Picture
printf("Converting Byte Array to Picture\n");
FILE *image;
image = fopen("c1.png", "w");
fwrite(p_array, 1, sizeof(p_array), image);
fclose(image);
```

Edit: Fixed sizeof(int) in server code.

Comment: There are several problems... you don't rewind your file, your server sizeof(1) should be sizeof(int), you're sending sizeof(buffer) not the actual content you read from fread(), and probably others.

Comment: How do i "rewind" the file, or is there a better way to obtain the size of a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to seek to the beginning of the file before you read

```
fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(picture);
fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

or use `fstat` to get the file size.

Comment: If on Linux, you can also use [`pread()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pread) instead in order to read at a fixed position/offset of zero (always at the beginning of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Check `fread` and `fwrite` syntax:

`size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t n, FILE *fp);`

`size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t n, FILE *fp);`

In your case correct statement should be:

`fread(send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer), 1, picture);`

`fwrite(p_array, sizeof(p_array), 1,image);`

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old post, I must highlight a few problems in the original code :

- feof(picture) is always false after fopen. You must always make a read before calling feof
- read(new_sock, p_array, size) is not guaranteed to read size bytes, it depends on the value of size, network load, server load,...

A correct (at least more robust) version would be :

```
//Send Picture as Byte Array (without need of a buffer as large as the image file)
printf("Sending Picture as Byte Array\n");
char send_buffer[BUFSIZE]; // no link between BUFSIZE and the file size
int nb = fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer), picture);
while(!feof(picture)) {
    write(sock, send_buffer, nb);
    nb = fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer), picture);
    // no need to bzero
}
```

Same problem on server side :

```
//Read Picture Byte Array
printf("Reading Picture Byte Array\n");
char p_array[size];
char* current = p_array;
int nb = read(new_sock, current, size);
while (nb >= 0) {
    current = current + nb;
    nb = read(new_sock, current, size);
}
```

On server side you can avoid the creation of a buffer as large a image file (which might be a problem with large images) :

```
//Read Picture Byte Array and Copy in file
printf("Reading Picture Byte Array\n");
char p_array[BUFSIZE];
FILE *image = fopen("c1.png", "w");
int nb = read(new_sock, p_array, BUFSIZE);
while (nb > 0) {
    fwrite(p_array, 1, nb, image);
    nb = read(new_sock, p_array, BUFSIZE);
}
fclose(image);
```